# How to make Generated Reference Number Using PHP

Tags: php

I'm struggling in making my own Reference number or Control number.

I create A database In PHPmyadmin I name by **db_aw** and my table is **tbl_users**

My scenerio is If I insert the data if in database the first reference would be 202112290001
that ref is base on YYYMMDD 0001

my question is if I insert another data in database I want the output like this 202112290002
and everytime the data is increase I would like to get the output by this 2021122901112 and so on. untill the zero in last digit is gone and continues to increment.

I'm strugging to code this. I hope you help me .

here's my Code:

```
<?php
// 20211229/0001
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","db_aw") or die("Connection Failed!");
$num = "0000";


if (isset($_POST['btn_submit'])) {
    $txt_control = $_POST['txt_control'];

    $generate_key = date('Y').date('m').date('d'); 
    $sql_uid = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM tbl_users");
    if ($count_uid = mysqli_num_rows($sql_uid) > 0) {
        while ($rows_id = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql_uid)) {
            
            $i = ($rows_id['uid'] + 1);
            $concatnumber = $generate_key.$i;
        }
    }else{
            $i = 1000;
            $num = strrev($i);
            $concatnumber = $generate_key.$num; 
    }   

    $sql = mysqli_query($conn,"insert into tbl_users (control_number,uid) values ('$concatnumber','$num')");
    if ($sql){
        echo 'Success!';
    }   
    mysqli_close($conn);
}


?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

<form method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="txt_control">
    <button type="submit" name="btn_submit" id="btn_submit">Click</button>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

My table in database
[image: tb_user]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

My pseudo-code would be something like

```
$a = "20211229" ; / probably get this from a date function for today.
$q = "select control_number from tbl_users where control_number like '$a%' order by control_number desc limit 1";
execute query
if a_row_found {
  retrieve row
  new_suffix = last four digits of control_number and increment by one
  } else{
  new_suffix = "0001"
  }
insert using $a . new_suffix
```

Of course you'll have to code the PHP yourself there, and you wouldn't just stick the start value into the query, you'd use a prepared statement.

Your code reads all values from your table, which will be annoying and time-consuming when you have 8000 per day for a year. You don't specify a sort order, so you've no idea that the last on returned will be the one with the highest value.

My query only returns those that start with the appropriate date, sorts them in descending order and only returns either the first one (because of the DESC sort order, that's the highest value) or none at all. If it returns a row, just add one to the value, and if it does not, just assign it the "first" value "0001".

Of course, you'd also want some code to deal with the situation where the suffix hits 9999, because just blindly incrementing it won't be any use there. Unless in your scenario that can never happen.

I'm also not sure it's a good idea to build up a number like this - will you be using the information in it for any purposes, particularly for searching or sorting? If so, you might be better off storing the date (as a proper date column) and a generic auto-incrementing UID, and letting the query handle things.